# Windows Phone Folder Picker - Show files

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, folderbrowserdialog

I have following code:

```
//open folder picker ui
FolderPicker openPicker = new FolderPicker();
openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
//openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".db");
openPicker.CommitButtonText = "Choose location";
openPicker.ContinuationData["Operation"] = "OpenFolder";
openPicker.PickFolderAndContinue();
```

This code works, but files arend't displayed; in all folders say: "This folder is empty", which is very missleading. 
Even with uncommenting the line `openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".db");` nothing is displayed although there are somje .db files.
Is there any possibility to show files in a folder picker?

Comment: No I didn't. But I dont understand how this is related to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course this code will give you "This folder is empty", you looking for "**.db**" **files** not **folders** :

Try this ( Change "**FolderPicker**" to "**FileOpenPicker**" )  :

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".db");
openPicker.CommitButtonText = "Choose location";
openPicker.ContinuationData["Operation"] = "OpenFolder";
openPicker.PickMultipleFilesAndContinue();
```

**EDIT :** In case of using "FolderPicker" to slect files, "This folder is empty" mean there is no "folders" ( not files ) in this folder .

Comment: I have to look for folders, because I need to have access to a whole directory to safe and read different files. There is not only one db file. If I use the FilePicker, the user would have to pick all the files. But they might not even exist at the time, the folder is chosen.

Comment: Okay, I got you. In this case there is no problem . I mean "This folder is empty" mean there is no "folders" ( not files ) in this folder . so even if you have ".db" files on  your folder the message will showed "This folder is empty" .. there is no folders.

Comment: Yeah. It just might be a little confusing for the user and I was wondering if it is possible to show the files, when selecting folders. Seems like its is not.

Comment: Yeah that's right. but I still can't understand why there is a FileTypeFilter for FolderPicker, It seems like it's useless for Windows Phone .