# Why there is a "FileTypeFilter" for "FolderPicker" in Windows Phone 8.1 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

When I tried to solve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380887/windows-phone-folder-picker-show-files/27381901#27381901), I came up with new one .

It's make sense to me that there is a "**FileTypeFilter**" for "**FileOpenPicker**" to pick a special files :

```
FileOpenPicker filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
filePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
filePicker.CommitButtonText = "Choose location";
filePicker.ContinuationData["Operation"] = "OpenFolder";
filePicker.PickMultipleFilesAndContinue();
```

But why there is a "**FileTypeFilter**" for "**FolderPicker**", since we only need to pick folder, Or Is there any use of "**FileTypeFilter**" for "**FolderPicker**" ?

```
FolderPicker openPicker = new FolderPicker();
openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
openPicker.CommitButtonText = "Choose location";
openPicker.ContinuationData["Operation"] = "OpenFolder";
openPicker.PickFolderAndContinue();
```